# jQuery JSON help

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

okay I'm new to jQuery and JSON but I have now done so I got some information from the database in JSON format and now I want to show the results in a nice way but I don't know how ;)

what I want is to show 5 newest threads on my page so will this script try to load all the time or do I need to do something else?

I want it to show the 5 newest threads and when there somes a new thread i should slide down and the 6 threads at the bottom should disappear

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON('ajax/forumThreads', function(data) {
    //$('<p>' + data[0].overskrift + '</p>').appendTo('#updateMe > .overskrift');

    $('<div class="overskrift">' + data[0].overskrift + '</div>') {
        $(this).hide().appendTo('updateMe').slideDown(1000);
    }

    //alert(data[0].overskrift);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Kim, welcome to SO! Can you please edit your question, it is a bit difficult to understand what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @karim79: I think he just wants to show 5 things, and when a fetch from the data source reveals a newer thing, put it at the top of the list, and slide the old one out. (Ajaxy always-show-the-newest-five-things)

Comment: @karim79 sorry for my bad english, @thanatos thats what i want to do :)

Comment: How did you get on with this? Did my answer help you on your way?

Answer (score 0):

What is the structure of your server side object?
Lets say your server side object is one of these (c#):

```
public class ForumThread
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string PostedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Then your javascript function would access each property as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON(
        'ajax/forumThreads', 
        function(data) {
            alert(data.Title);
            alert(data.Content);
            alert(data.PostedBy);
        }
    });
</script>
```

If you wanted to return a list of items, you might have a container response object as follows:

```
public class ForumThreadList
{
    public List<ForumThread> Threads { get; set; }
}
```

..and you would access the list as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON(
        'ajax/forumThreads', 
        function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.Threads.length; i++) {
                    alert(data.Threads[i].Title);
                    alert(data.Threads[i].Content);
                    alert(data.Threads[i].PostedBy);
                }
        }
    });
</script>
```

To add a new item you might try something like this:

Assuming your html is:

```
<body>
    <div id="threadContainer">
        <!-- javascript will add divs like this:
            <div class='threadItem'>Content!</div>
        -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Your javascript might be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON(
        'ajax/forumThreads', 
        function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Threads.length; i++) {
                var threadItem = $("<div class='threadItem'>" + data.Threads[i].Title + "</div>");
                var existingItemCount = $("#threadContainer > .threadItem").length;
                if (existingItemCount >= 5) {
                    $("#threadContainer > .threadItem:last").remove();
                }
                if (existingItemCount == 0) {
                    $("#threadContainer").append(threadItem);   
                }
                else {
                    threadItem.insertBefore($("#threadContainer > .threadItem:first")); 
                }

            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I've done all of this in notepad++, so hopefully it all works. Give it a go and let me know how you get on.